# Cannot boot from Ubuntu live usb (pcie bus error)

Tags: boot, live-usb

I recently created an Ubuntu 20.04 Live USB via Rufus but when I try to start from the USB, I get a screen full of messages like

```
pcieport 0000:00:01.2: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, id=000a(Transmitter ID)
pcieport 0000:00:01.2: AER: device [1022:1483] error status/mask=00001000/00004000
```

flooding my screen.

Nevertheless, I cannot even boot up my Live USB. I haven’t seen any good solutions on the web.

My PC is custom built with Nvidia gtx graphics and an MSI x-570 motherboard. I don’t see how either would cause this to occur.

How do I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: No it doesn’t, sadly.

Comment: You need to add much more information about your system and how you created the LiveUSB. As it stands, there is nothing to add. Also what did you try to fix it? The link I gave has a lot of options.

Comment: I can’t even update grub parameters since I can’t even boot from a live usb.

Comment: What do you mean by "boot from a live usb"? You should be able to get into grub menu. It looks that you can boot Linux kernel, because the messages come from there. So try to follow the guide how to boot with `nomodeset`.

Comment: I did the nomodeset option and I still get these messages on the screen.

Comment: I managed to fix this. I used pci=noaer command to get to a live usb screen.

Answer (score 0):

I have failed with Rufus (and some other programs) to create a Ubuntu Live USB stick from Windows but when I used [balenaEtcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) I succeeded. If even that fails, then try the [Universal USB Installer](https://itsfoss.com/create-live-usb-of-ubuntu-in-windows/). My failures may be due to my total lack of knowledge in Windows.